# How to get smooth edges on text object?

Tags: edges, text-object

I'm working with some text objects for some motion graphics. However, the edges come are really rough:

[image]

Initially I figured it was just caused by lower-res rendering in the 3D view, however, it also shows up when I render it out at 100%:

[image]

I'm using the Cycles render engine, rendering using CUDA on a GTX 750 Ti, and here's the node layout for that text:

[image]

Is there any way I can improve the quality of the letters?

**EDIT** As requested by Todd McIntosh

Wireframe:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you are talking about AntiAliasing here?

Comment: @zeffii Yes, that's what I'm going for. I tried changing the Anti-aliasing samples to 16, but I doesn't help any :/

Comment: Ah I misunderstood the problem. There's completely different approach then of course. You can use alpha channel of the text and blur it in the render (one way). However you should include information about render engine used

Comment: @MrZak I've updated my question with what I thought was best. Let me know if that helps and/or if you need/meant more.

Comment: Please post the blend file for an accurate answer. I would question why you are using the Object TextCoords to drive ColorContrast to drive the MixFac between an Emission and Transparent shader. Is that necessary for pure white text?

Comment: Also, perhaps post a wireframe of the text. Are they still curve objects? What is the curve subdivision set to?

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh Sorry for the delay, I've updated my Q. As for the node layout, that's for an effect I'm attempting to achieve where the text appears letter by letter. See here for an example: https://youtu.be/8gIcPO4FFKU. As for it being a curve object & curve subdivision, I believe it's a curve object and I have no idea what the curve subdivision is set to. Where would I find that?

Comment: @OP I very recently ran into a similar issue... (Although it was an After Effects to Final Cut Pro issue). My AE renders were crisp and clean. Similar renders in Blender were crisp and clean. But in the clients final render there were jagged edges. So, while I don't have an answer for you: What file type are you rendering out to? And in what application are the artifacts showing up?

Comment: One last thought... Maybe it is the font you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you are suffering from a lack of [anti-aliasing](http://[0.028222,%200.429114,%200.496922,%201.000000]).

If you are using cycles, you'll need more than one sample (*Properties > Render > Sampling*) in order to get good anti-aliasing. Try maybe 15 or so, and increase until the result is smooth enough for your liking.
Keep an eye on the rendertime though.

[image]

If your animation consists entirely of flat colors, I would recommend using BI or 
[OpenGL render](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/opengl.html) instead.

## OpenGL

The OpenGL render operates using the same techniques for the viewport and realtime games. In other words, it renders nearly instantaneously (especially for flat colors).

To enable anti-aliasing when using OpenGL render, enable *Anti-Aliasing* in *Info > Render > OpenGL options* and choose a suitable number of AA samples (more == slower but smoother):

[image]

## Blender Internal

If you need a little more than just flat colors (motion blur, for instance), then you might consider BI. While perhaps slower than OpenGL (depending on your hardware), it's still much faster than Cycles when it comes to flat shading:

[image]

Comment: I actually ended up taking a break from Blender/video work in general for a bit and have just now come back to it and while initially everything was rendering out greyscale, I switched the viewport to Material mode and then using OpenGL worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have to manually smooth the edges by converting the Text Objects into a Mesh or Curve Object. This is easily done by selecting your Text Object, and hitting [Alt + C].

Comment: I tried this and it helped a very small amount, but the edges are still very rough. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the interpolation for the text.

After that you can convert the text to a curve or mesh by pressing Alt + C