# Why is my text render so weird?

Tags: rendering, text-object

[image]
I am trying to render this 2D Animation but my text always appears like this. I have tried every little solution on the internet but nothing works.

- I am using EEVE Renderer.
- Sampling: Render: 64
- Resolution 1920x1080

Someone told me to use emission shader which improved its brightness but it is still harsh/pixelated.

(text and stroke are not in the same plane, text is a little above that.)

Tried Cycles renderer, higher resolution, depth, extrude. Nothing worked.

Any help?

Here's the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mvFENCrmU1Cngdzc9cq1xsSp-NKw8EQW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: what is the problem? the pixelate text?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. But Yes. Even at higher resolution.

Comment: Have added the file, if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the file and I think that every font - if viewed in a "too small" bitmap image - shows pixels.

If there is too much info and too few pixels, it's normal that if you zoom in you'll see a not perfect smooth shape (with antialias you can smooth a little bit the result).

In summary, if you want to represent a vector images (svg, font) into a bitmap image, you need to have enough resolution on the target image if you don't want pixelated results.

Check this post about the same problem:
[How to get smooth edges on text object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43515/how-to-get-smooth-edges-on-text-object)

Comment: Ok. So I guess not much can be done. Thanks for your help. You've put my mind at ease.